# Can't remove index.php without getting a 404, .htaccess redirect not working, why?

Tags: url, config, routing, 404-page

So this is not my first craft build, and basically, it's identical to my last setup on the craft front, I can't see anything wrong, but I can't remove index.php without causing a 404. I've tried the .htaccess fix, not luck. The last site I did simply had "deny from all" in .htaccess, but it didn't need index.php, so I don't see why I would need to change that for it to work? Is there anywhere else I can look for a settings change that might allow for cleaning up the urls?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `.htaccess` file in your public HTML folder?

Comment: Which highlights my rookie error, wrong .htaccess file! Cheers Brad!

Comment: Hah... happens to the best of us.  Can you post that as an official answer?

Answer (score 3):

Check and make sure your .htaccess file is in your public HTML folder `public/.htaccess`!

If you do not include your .htaccess file in your public folder, Craft will display your home page properly, but all other pages will fail to load unless you add `index.php?p=` in your URL.

Without `.htaccess`:
http://website.com/mypagethatreallyexists = 404

Without `.htaccess`:
http://website.com/index.php?p=mypagethatreallyexists = Your page

With `.htaccess`:
http://website.com/mypagethatreallyexists = Your page

Answer (score 1):

Try setting [`omitScriptNameInUrls`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#omitScriptNameInUrls) to true in your `craft/config/general.php` file.

Comment: Yeah tried it, it gets rid of it when I use links but then just throws up a 404 since it's not directing properly...does that make sense?